# How do I stop md-cards from stretching images to full vertical height?

Tags: css, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

I'm experimenting with Angular Material on my personal blog and I've decided to try implementing cards on my main page. Everything looks great on my macbook but when I view the page on a windows machine my images are stretched vertically.

After looking a bit closer, it seems that my images are being stretched to their full height.

**My Code:**

I'm doing this in an ASP.NET Razor view like so:

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <md-card>
        <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageUrl)" class="md-card-image" alt="Washed Out">
        <md-card-title>
            <md-card-title-text>
                <span class="md-headline">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</span>
            </md-card-title-text>
        </md-card-title>
        <md-card-content>
            <p>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </p>
            <hr />
            <md-chips>

                @foreach (var tag in item.Tags)
                {
                    <md-chip>@tag.Name</md-chip>
                }
            </md-chips>
        </md-card-content>
        <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="space-between center">
            <div class="md-body-2 lightgrey">
                @String.Format(item.Created.ToLongDateString())
            </div>
            <md-button>@Html.ActionLink("View Post", "ViewPost", "Posts", new { id = item.Id, slug = item.URL }, null)</md-button>
        </md-card-actions>
    </md-card>
}
```

### Question

How do I stop my images from stretching to 100% of their height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular-material.scss

```
md-card{

> img,
> :not(md-card-content) img {
box-sizing: border-box;
display: flex;
flex: 0 0 auto;
width: 100%;
height: 100% !important;
 }
}
```

So because of the `100% !important` of height value you can not override height in inline styling. so I would suggest to change this line to

`height: 100%`

(appropriate css file is angular-material.css just search for that)
and

```
    <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageUrl)" class="md-card-image" alt="Washed Out" height="150">
```

define height of each `img` element as inline using `height` attribute.

Comment: I am using the latest version(1.1.0). But in your case you can directly define `height` attribute in `img` tag or `inline css` will work.

Comment: Adding a concrete height attribute does work, however, it defeats the purpose of dynamic content templates. I'll accept this as the answer, because it does help with the problem I asked about, but I don't think I'll take this route. If I find a better solution, I'll post back. Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you make all your images of appropriate size you won't need to use this approach plus I'm sure developers will come up with something concrete.

Comment: These are just test images, however I should be able to add images of any size I want and make them fit easily. It's common task and I've done it in my CSS in the past. There's obviously something I'm missing here with angular material.

Comment: Yeah. This library is still in it's early phase. I am sure they will add this future

Comment: I figured it out. I just needed to wrap my img tag with a div tag to break Angular Materials CSS rule. I'll leave your answer selected as I'm sure it'll be helpful to others in the future, plus I don't like accepting my own answers. thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

All I had to do in the end was wrap my image in a `div` tag. This `div` obviously breaks the Angular Material CSS rule that was in control of styling my image.

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <md-card>
        <!-- add div tag here! -->
        <div>
            <img src="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ImageUrl)" class="md-card-image" alt="Washed Out">
        </div>
        <!-- end div tag here! -->
        <md-card-title>
            <md-card-title-text>
                <span class="md-headline">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</span>
            </md-card-title-text>
        </md-card-title>
        <md-card-content>
            <p>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </p>
            <hr />
            <md-chips>

                @foreach (var tag in item.Tags)
                {
                    <md-chip>@tag.Name</md-chip>
                }
            </md-chips>
        </md-card-content>
        <md-card-actions layout="row" layout-align="space-between center">
            <div class="md-body-2 lightgrey">
                @String.Format(item.Created.ToLongDateString())
            </div>
            <md-button>@Html.ActionLink("View Post", "ViewPost", "Posts", new { id = item.Id, slug = item.URL }, null)</md-button>
        </md-card-actions>
    </md-card>
}
```

Comment: Did you have my issue here after you added the div: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43527005/md-card-image-with-overflowhidden-max-height-kills-100-width ?