# md-card-image with overflow:hidden + max-height kills 100% width

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

Using Angular 2, I was trying to partly show a cover image by using

```
img[md-card-image] {
   hidden: overflow;
   max-heigth: 160px;
}
```

However, Angular decides that it boxes the image inside during the overflow. I cannot seem to figure out how to get the image fill the whole top of the card.

[image: cover image not 100%]

**Edit 1**

If I do not use the above css, and instead change the div which wraps my cover image to `margin-bottom: -50%;` which moves the text up on top of the image; however, in this case, I cannot set a background to the content on the card. for the part of the text that runs over the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of trying different things, I finally came up with a solution. I had to remove the `md-card-image` and manually do it with divs. I guess the material design css is messing with it causing the issue when you add the `hidden: overflow` to the container.

Here's what it looks like:

[image: solution]

My styling for the material card:

```
md-card {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 20px;

    .cover-wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        height: 160px;

        .cover-image {
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-size: cover;
        }
    }

    .cover-footer {
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
        margin: -50px 0px 0px 0px;
        padding: 10px;

        div[md-card-title] {
            font-weight: bold;
            width: 100%;
            font-size: $font-size-large;
        }
    }
}
```

The html for the material card:

```
<md-card class="mat-elevation-z2" mat-whiteframe="8" fxLayout="column">
    <div class="cover-wrapper" fxFlex>
        <div class="cover-image" [style.background-image]="'url(' + _cover + ')' | safeStyle"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="cover-footer" fxFlex>
        <div md-card-title fxFlex>{{ _title }}</div>
    </div>
    <md-card-content>
        <div [innerHtml]="_text | safeHtml" id="markdown"></div>
    </md-card-content>
</md-card>
```